# Calculate all prime numbers $x$, where $x^{18} - 1$ is divisible by $28728$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, prime-factorization

**Question:** *Calculate all prime numbers $x$, where $x^{18} - 1$ is divisible by $28728$*

Apparently, the answer is all prime numbers except $2, 3, 7,$ and $19.$ I did some prime factorisation and found that $28728 =$ $2^3\times3^3\times7\times19$ and spotted that the numbers that $x$ cannot be with it. However, I still don't know why and how to prove that the answer can be all prime numbers except $2, 3, 7,$ and $19.$

Any help would be extremely appreciated :)

Comment: Fermats theorem that really fits in the margin guarantees that $x^{p-1}-1$ is divisible by $p$ iff $x$ is prime to $p$. Apply this for $p$ among the numbers above. (And also note $x^{18}-1$ is divisible by $x^d-1$, where $d$ divides $18$.)

Comment: For example $37^{18}-1$ is divisible by $28728.$

Comment: Consider $x^{18}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$ for $m=8,9,7,19$.  By the Chinese remainder theorem, a simultaneous solution to all of them solves the original problem.  Fermat's little theorem, and Euler's generalization dispose of all $4$ cases.

Comment: Use Carmichael function $\lambda(n)$ which is defined as follows : if $\displaystyle n=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{e_i}$ then $$\lambda(n)=l.c.m. \{\lambda(p_1^{e_1}),\cdots,\lambda(p_k^{e_k})\}$$ and 
$$\lambda(p^{e})=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\phi(p^e)}{2}\text { for powers of 2 greater or equal than 3 }\\ \\ \phi(p^e)\text { otherwise }\end{cases}$$ where $\phi$ is the Euler's totient function.

Answer (score 1):

The Carmichael function $\lambda(n)$ gives the smallest exponent $k$, for which $$x^k\equiv 1\mod n$$ holds for all $x$ coprime to $n$.

Because of $\lambda(28728)=18$ , the congruence $$x^{18}\equiv 1\mod 28728$$ is satisfied for all $x$ coprime to $28728$ and in particular for all primes except $2,3,7$ and $19$.