# Which is the smallest natural number $m$ with $m> 1$ for which the following relation does not hold: $ 11 ^ {2018} \equiv 1 \pmod m $

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Which is the smallest natural number $m$ with $m > 1$, for which the following relation does not hold:

$$11^{2018} \equiv 1 \pmod m $$

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem shows that $m\leq2018$

Comment: Not that many $m$'s to try, since $11^{2018}\equiv 0\pmod{11}$.

Comment: Closely related to questions asked the past couple days, e.g.[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3270309/242)  and [this (now deleted)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3269645/242).

Comment: @lulu the answer may not be prime, a number can be $1\bmod 2$ but may not be $1\bmod4$.

Comment: @JulianMejia  Ah, good point.  Still, not a lot of numbers to search.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** For $m = 11$, it obviously does not hold. So you have only $9$ numbers to try, 
 namely $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$.

Comment: Another hint: check the (non-trivial) cases by using Fermat's/Euler's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

after the clues that you guys give i have figured out that $m =7$ and $$11^{2018} \equiv 2 \pmod 7 $$
Is that correct?

Comment: On target.  But you needed not figure out the residue exactly.  Since $11\not\equiv\pm1\bmod 7$, its powers can be $\equiv 1$ only if the exponent is a multiple of $3$.